# C# DateTime Convert or Parse specific format?

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert the following string to a DateTime value in c#:

> 1 March 2012

But I keep getting this error when calling Convert.ToDateTime or DateTime.Parse.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I think a custom date format needs to be used but I have no idea what the format would be.

How can I convert a string in the format above to a DateTime value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(yourString, "d MMMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Comment: +1 though I thought answers required some sort of content beyond just code.

Comment: @JoeTuskan - Something is better than nothing :D

Comment: @phoog - I understand this is a fairly simple question which only really deserves a single line of code in response, but even a link to the documentation would be helpful. Otherwise this answer is only helpful to those trying to parse the _exact same_ date time format. I thought we were trying to provide answers with lasting effects here...

Comment: @M.Babcock, for the record, I agree with you.

Comment: It's either an answer like this or closing the question as a duplicate.  A nice, well-detailed answer is probably not worth the effort for a question that comes up this often.

Answer (score 2):

you can find out the datetime patterns supported by getting the cultureinfo from the current thread.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string date = "1 03 2012";

            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern);
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(date));
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(date));


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
     string s = "1 March 2012";
     DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(s);
```